# OutOfMemoryException when creating many instances for class containing icon

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that contains an Image:

```
class AnyClass
{
    Image AnyImage;
    string AnyString;
}
```

I am having an `OutOfMemoryException` when I create more than 2000 instances of this class.
The images to be assigned to `AnyClass` are only 3 and icon sized.
Theses instances will serve as datasource for a ListView.

Is there a way to have the Image assigned by reference in `AnyClass`?
Or what is the way/pattern to handle such case?

EDITED:
Haven't tested the code, but this is similar to what is being done:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<AnyClass> lst = new List<AnyClass>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        lst.Add(new AnyClass() { AnyImage = ImageList.image1, AnyString = "test" });
    }
}

public class AnyClass
{
    public Image AnyImage;
    public string AnyString;
}

public class ImageList
{
    public static Image image1;
    public static Image image2;
    public static Image imgae3;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you have only 3 different images? Not sure if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes, only 3 different images. one of them will be assigned to `AnyImage`

Comment: Could you show more code? The MemoryException can happen when the image could not be load too!

Comment: @ibrahimBadredine Usually, you'll have a resource manager, that keeps track of your resources, so you won't end up with multiple copies of the same resource.

Comment: @ibrahimBadredine How are you currently creating the images? You should just be able to load the 3 images into `Image` variables prior to creating your 2000 other items, and then pass the relevant `Image` reference into the creation of an `AnyClass` instance. I suspect you are loading or "`new`ing up" 2000 duplicated images, although I'm not sure how you'd run out of memory for small icons (even 2000 of them, that isn't much really).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth this is my concern. How to pass the image by reference?  
(The machines running the program have low-specs)

Comment: @ibrahimBadredine : the image are already passing by reference, unless there is a hole in your code. That's why you need to show us the real code for creating the AnyClass instances.

Comment: I think you want the Flyweight Pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Comment: @ibrahimBadredine It looks like you are already only using 3 underlying images. Each reference to the image in `AnyClass` will either be 4 or 8 bytes depending on 32 or 64 bit. Perhaps the `AnyString` value is the culprit? We really need a sample application that shows the memory issue.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth ok. I will get back to you when I set it up. Thanks for support

Comment: Are you sure the references being used are the same? I know that Image inherits from MarshalByRefObject and this makes copies of an object as they move between AppDomains. Could you use the Object ID functionality in VS to ensure the image objects in your AnyClass aren't copies? I'm shooting from the hip on this one.

Comment: I don't get, why are you creating new `AnyClass` Objects and storing in a list of 2000 elements? If they're all the same image, why have it 2000 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have add a sample image in my resource project, and I have made two code :

This one throw a Memory Exception:

```
List<AnyClass> lst = new List<AnyClass>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
    lst.Add(new AnyClass() { AnyImage = ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Resources.Image1, AnyString = "test" });
}
```

This one doesn't:

```
var image1 = ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Resources.Image1;
List<AnyClass> lst = new List<AnyClass>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
    lst.Add(new AnyClass() { AnyImage = image1, AnyString = "test" });
}
```

In the task manager, you can see that the first code is using the memory unless there is no more.
The second code run immediatly.

Moreover, you can try this code :

```
var instance1 = ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Resources.Image1;
var instance2 = ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Resources.Image1;

Console.Write(instance1 == instance2); -- output false
```

So if you are using images in Resources of your project, you must to cache it first, else you will create a new instance of the image each time your are calling the resource.

Comment: That's because the resource manager does not cache the image, it loads it from the resource file each time. The fact that it's a property is a little code smell on the side of the code generator for the resource file, I've never particularly liked that generator.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is related to GDI+ handles, not memory. In particular, I expect you aren't *disposing* the images when done. Since `AnyClass` encapsulates an image, it feels like `AnyClass` should be `IDisposable`:

```
class AnyClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() {
        if(AnyImage != null) { AnyImage.Dispose(); AnyImage = null; }
    }
    Image AnyImage;
    string AnyString;
}
```

and then you should dispose (preferably via `using`) any such instances when you are done with them.

The point here is that each `Image` uses a GDI+ handle; that handle is released when either:

- the image is *disposed* (by your code, often via `using`)
- the image is *finalized* (during/after garbage collection)

If you have plenty of memory, garbage collection *won't run very often*, so the discarded handles won't be being released by garbage collection. That means you need to be vigilant to dispose each image properly when you are done with it.

The trick, though, is knowing when you are "done" with an image. If you dispose an `Image` that is still in use by the UI... bad things.